# Загружается ли изображение из общих стилей?

Tags: html, css

Для блока указаны разные фоны для разных разрешений.

```
.block {
    background-image: url(image1);
}

@media and screen (max-width: 600px) {
    .block {
        background-image: url(image1);
    }
}
```

Какое из изображений загрузится при открытии страницы на устройстве с разрешением меньше 600px:

- image1;
- image2;
- оба изображения?

Comment: "Image2 is a lie". Только второе.

Comment: У вас и там, и там image1. Кстати, рекомендую всякие неочевидные моменты по загрузке ресурсов проверять через devtools / network.